# distinct result by entire table when using cross apply on json and order by with case

Tags: sql-server, sql-order-by, case, distinct, outer-apply

I need to order my result by value from dictionary that stored as JSON in my table that equals a parameter.
In order to get it I'm using case on my order by to check if the value from the dictionary match the parameter.
After ordering the table I need to distinct the result however I'm getting an error and I couldn't figure it out.

here is my query:

```
declare @FilteredItemIDs -> temp table that filtered my items

declare @CurrentGroupID as int

select distinct item.*
from Items as items
    outer apply openjson(json_query(Data, '$.itemOrderPerGroup'), '$') as X
where items.ItemID in (select ItemID from @FilteredItemIDs )
order by case
    when @CurrentGroupID!= 0 and (JSON_VALUE(X.[Value], '$.Key') = @CurrentGroupID) then 1
    else 2 end,
    CONVERT(int, JSON_VALUE(X.[Value], '$.Value'))
```

Comment: `declare @FilteredItemIDs -> temp table that filtered my items`? `@FilteredItemIDs`is a [table] variable, not a temporary table. A temporary table would be defined using `CREATE TABLE #TempTable...`. Table variables and Temporary tables are *very* different.

Comment: Please supply sample data and expected output. What exact error are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you `DISTINCT` over a resultset, you are effectively using `GROUP BY` over all columns. So the `X.Value` doesn't exist anymore when you get to the `ORDER BY`.

Using `DISTINCT` is usually a code smell, it indicates that joins have not been thought through. In this case, you should probably place the `OPENJSON` inside a subquery, with `SELECT TOP (1)`, although it's hard to say without sample data and expected results.

```sql
select
  item.*
from Items as items
outer apply (
    select top (1)
      X.[Key],
      X.Value
    from openjson(Data, '$.itemOrderPerGroup')
      with (
          [Key] int,
          Value int
      ) as X
) X
where items.ItemID in (select ItemID from @FilteredItemIDs )
order by case
    when @CurrentGroupID != 0 and X.Key = @CurrentGroupID then 1
    else 2 end,
    X.[Value];
```

Note the correct use of `OPENJSON` with a JSON path and property names.

If what you actually want is to filter the `OPENJSON` results, rather than ordering by them, then you can do that in an `EXISTS`

```sql
select
  item.*
from Items as items
outer apply  X
where items.ItemID in (select ItemID from @FilteredItemIDs )
  and exists (select 1
    from openjson(Data, '$.itemOrderPerGroup')
      with (
          [Key] int,
          Value int
      ) as X
    where @CurrentGroupID = 0 or X.Key = @CurrentGroupID
);
```